# Team 2 wants extra benefits because team 1's requirements changed

Tags: management, salary, work-time

I have two teams, Team A and Team B. They do different work. The working hours of team A were recently changed (to 6-14hrs and 14-22 hrs), and the company decided to pay extra for Team A.

Team B does not require changes to their schedule. After hearing from Team A, they want do their CTC corrections, they state they are also willing to work the hours of Team A, and they want the extra pay as well.

Please suggest a course of action.

Comment: "CTC corrections"?

Comment: I suggest that you spell out what you mean by "CTC". A quick Google search gives me an estimate of the possible meanings of "CTC" in the order of three figures.

Comment: A course of action for what?

Comment: While the cynical person in me would want to buy the smallest fiddle I could find and play it for team B (albeit badly since I don't play the fiddle) in reality I would simply say, "What others are paid isn't relevant to what YOU are paid. We needed Team A to shift their hours and felt it deserved a bump in pay, that need is covered and we have no need for anyone else to shift hours." If Team B wants a bump in pay they need to provide some kind of reason. Want more money? Make me feel like I need to be giving you more money through what YOU bring to the negotiating table, not what Team A did.

Comment: Sounds like you need to buck up and be a manager.  No is a perfectly acceptable answer in this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing about the whole "treat everybody equally to be fair" thing. We're not all clones of the same person. We all do things differently, have different strengths and weaknesses, and frankly, don't always deserve to be treated the same.

Sure, I'd like to get paid as much as an all-star athlete, but the fact is I'm kind of fat, balding, old, and am about as coordinated as a frilly little pink-skirt-wearing girl. So, should I make $15million dollars a year like a renowned quarterback? No. Why? Because I don't deserve it, and fairness in this situation is crap.

To your situation, you have a team whose tasks require them to work more hours and they are getting paid accordingly. This other team is saying "Hey, that's not fair, we want moar moneees too, and we can work moar hours!" Hell no. If you give them the extra time, they'll just find a way to fit thier current workload into the new schedule.

So, how do you handle this? Make sure the change for team A is temporary and tell team B to pound sand. If they have an actual requirement that results in real overtime, they can have it too. But until then, they should STFU and get back to work.

Comment: I don't think you need to make sure the change for Team A is temporary.  Even if we were clones, A and B are doing different things.  Different work = different pay scales.

Comment: Mike, please don't stereotype frilly little pink-skirt-wearing girls as uncoordinated.  I've known many who were terrific athletes.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody wants to feel like they're treated unequally, but that doesn't always mean treating everyone the same. The window washer can't expect to be allowed to work from home just because someone else does.

A team agreed to a change in their work to benefit the company and they were compensated. This isn't all that different from giving someone extra pay for over-time. You can't afford to give everyone an hour of over-time just because one person happened to get it in an emergency.

Team B needs to understand that they will be called on to do something else or change their schedule to benefit the company and if they step up to it, they'll be compensated. Business needs change, so this isn't something you can promise to happen over-night.

Of course, all of this is moot if your company has some sort of policy about paying everyone the same no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

There was a business need met by altering Team A's hours.  Meeting this need caused inconvenience to the members of Team A and as such they were compensated for their inconvenience.  There is no business need to be met by altering Team B's hours therefor there is no business value in their proposed course of action.